# How to display n records per line in Logcat in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following code convert a list to a string and display to Logcat,  but all records are displayed in one line. I hope to display top 10 records per line in Logcat in Android Studio 3.0, how can I do ?

**Note:** `Log.e("My", logList.joinToString("<Br/>", limit =10, truncated = "...more..."))` doesn't work

```
 val logList=LogHandler().getListAllLog()
 Log.e("My", logList.joinToString("|", limit =10, truncated = "...more..."))
```

Comment: How about iterating through your list and then call Log on each itteration?

Comment: you can use **\n** or looping iteration.

Comment: appending \n will work in logs string

Comment: Do you want to only display the "top 10 records and discard the rest" or "split up your list and display 10 records per line" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
val strings = ArrayList<String>()
    strings.add("This is line1")
    strings.add("This is line2")
    strings.add("This is line3")
    display(strings)
```

You should iterator list. Try this:

```
fun display(strings: List<String>) {
    for (str in strings) {
        Log.e("YourTag", str)
    }
}
```

Comment: Log.e("My", logList.joinToString("\n", limit =10, truncated = "...more...")) is OK

Answer (score 1):

you can chop up your List using chunked() method.
e.g. if you want to log 10 records per line, then just call chunked(10).

```
 //assuming logList is an array of String. 
 //you can use logList.chunked directly if it is a List.

 val batchSize = 10 //chop up to 10 per batch

 logList.asList().chunked(batchSize)
            .forEach{subList -> Log.d("My", subList.joinToString("|" )) }
```

Comment: Log.e("My", logList.joinToString("\n", limit =10, truncated = "...more...")) is OK

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use "\n" for new line,in logs.

For example:

`Log.e(TAG,"Hello \n World");`

which will give output as

```
Hello 
 World
```